# CSS : Parent won't clearing child with absolute position

Tags: css, css-position

So i have 3 box:

```
Box 1 = red
Box 2 = blue
Box 3 = yellow

Box 1 contains Box 2
Box 2 contains Box 3

Box3 are floated divs and have been cleared using extra div style="clear:both"
```

I want to have Box 2 as an absolute position to Box 1 like this :
http://i301.photobucket.com/albums/nn42/b1rk0ff/done_zpsd3cd25c0.png

I have tried like this but won't work :

Html :

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    testing
</div>
```

Style :

```
    .box1 { 
        width:300px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
    }

    .box2 {
        width: 200px;
        background-color:blue;
        position: absolute;
        right:-100px;
        top:30px;
    }   

    .box3 {
        height:50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-color:yellow;
        float:left;
        margin:10px;
        color:black;
    }
```

Here's the codepen :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kkirs?editors=110

Anybody could help?

Thank you

Comment: It will not happen because when you add position absolute the div(box2) is like having a separate object and the parent(box1) will not extend to his height.

Comment: Just delete postition: absolute;

Comment: is there any another way? instead of just give box1 (parent) min-height attribute? thanks

Comment: Why does box2 need to be `position:absolute`?...would be my question.

Comment: @VincentBeltman i need absolute position, to position the box2 to the parent element (box1). Here's the final result : http://i301.photobucket.com/albums/nn42/birkoffkeren/done_zpsd3cd25c0.png

Comment: No..you don't - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wDihs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about removing `position:relative` from `.box1`, and change `position:absolute` to `.position:relative` in `.box2`

See snipet below, and take a look at the comments in `.box2`

```css
.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  right: -150px; /* changed this value to -150px » was -100px */
  top: 10px; /* changed this value to 10px » was 30px */
  padding:10px /* add padding as you need and if you need */
}
.box3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  testing
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution you need to compensated the top value on box2 with padding on box1 so box2 doesn't overflow box1 http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/1mjywa1v/4/

Comment: this fiddle is not my snippet. I also changed values in `.box2`, did you run my snippet?

Comment: @dippas yes I did I saw you changed the `top` value of .box2 so that it doesn't overflow. The point I am trying to show is that the top value of .box2 moves the bleu box out of the flow and therefore it can overlap or overflow other elements. Maybe OP doesn't care about that though.

Comment: @web-tiki as always I'm only basing my answers on the code I have in front of me. thanks for your input ;)

Comment: this is the final result OP wanted: http://s301.photobucket.com/user/birkoffkeren/media/done_zpsd3cd25c0.png.html so I'm guessing OP doesn't want text in .box1

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just set a fixed height for `.box1`?

```css
  .box1 { 
    width:300px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    height:250px;
}

.box2 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
    position: absolute;
    right:-100px;
    top:30px;
}   

.box3 {
    height:50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div class="box3">box-3</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    testing
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace position: absolute by position: relative.

Answer (score 0):

since box2 is absolute box 1 does not know the height of it's children,

you will need to revert to using both relative elements (or no position definition at all) and solve this problem with `margin-left` and `margin-top`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, this is what i want.

Hope it helps another newbie like me. :)

```css
.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  right: -150px; /* changed this value to -150px » was -100px */
  top: 10px; /* changed this value to 10px » was 30px */
  padding:10px /* add padding as you need and if you need */
}
.box3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  testing
</div>
```

```css
.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  right: -150px; /* changed this value to -150px » was -100px */
  top: 10px; /* changed this value to 10px » was 30px */
  padding:10px /* add padding as you need and if you need */
}
.box3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div class="box3">box-3</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  testing
</div>
```